# List in Laravel with more than 2 column

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Using Laravel 5, I'm trying to make a list of countries in a dropdown.
I use this syntax :

```
$countries= Countries::get('name', 'id');
```

And then, with blade

```
{!! Form::select('countries', $countries) !!}
```

This gives me a nice list, but I would like to set a custom attribute on every country. This argument is the continent of the country, something like "data-continent='X'".

This continent is a column of my table "countries".

Comment: This doesn't look like something you'll be able to do using `Form::select`. I think you'll just need to loop and output the options with your custom format.

Comment: Yep it's a solution, I'd prefer a nice way to do that.

Comment: I'm going to have to agree with Don't Panic on this one. What he means by loop, is just do a foreach over $countries in blade and generate the actual select values that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the continent column to your query

```
$countries= Countries::get('name', 'id', 'continent');
```

Then loop over the results and ouput using any format you prefer.

```
<select name="country">
@foreach ($countries as $c)
    <option data-continent="{{ $c->continent }}" value="{{ $c->id }}">{{ $c->name }}</option>
@endforeach
</select>
```